# Adding Title to Wordpress Sub-Nav Menu?

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation

Is there any way to display the title of the parent nav item in the sub-menu li list Wordpress generates?

As it is wordpress spits out for  a nav button labeled "Radio"

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-    page menu-item-34"><a href="#">Satellite</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-33"><a href="#">Online</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-35"><a href="#">Terrestial</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to have it generate :

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
  <h2> Radio</h2>
<li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-    page menu-item-34"><a href="#">Satellite</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-33"><a href="#">Online</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-35"><a href="#">Terrestial</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any help is appreciated as always, thank you.

Comment: Are you using the menu system in Appearance > Menu's?
If so try adding a custom link, with the URL as #, not the nicest solution but will achieve what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you are using the wp_list_pages to list the navigation, you could pass the title_li parameter to bring up a title for your navigation. Like this:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=<h2>' . __('Radio') . '</h2>' ); ?>
```

[Source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages)!